# How to execute an .exe file including blank spaces in it

Tags: windows, batch-file, exe

So normally I have several *.bat files to automate some things in my computer.

But I'm kinda stuck in this call...

```
cd "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\program2Execute"
start program has spaces.exe
```

I don't get the app executed, instead I get a cmd window with the cd command result, nothing else. I tried to quote "program has spaces.exe" but it doesn't get executed I get the window duplicated instead.

Apologize if this is kinda dumb to ask, but I have spent quite time looking for the answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the `start` command:

```
start "" "a program with spaces.exe"
```

`start` will use the first double quoted string as the title and the 2nd as the command.

Or don't use `start`:

```
"a program with spaces.exe"
```

Comment: You are the man!